# FormArray returing value as array of array instead of array of object in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive form in my angular application, where I have used `formArray` to add dynamically `formControl`. But when I submit the form, it's value is type array of array, but I think it should be array of object.

See here:
[image]

My Component Code:

```js
export class StudentFormComponent {
  form;
  constructor(private studentService: StudentService,
    private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      documents: fb.array([])
    });
  }

  get documentCtrl() {
    return (this.form.get('documents') as FormArray);
  }

  addControl() {
    this.documentCtrl.push(new FormControl(''));
  }

  save() {
    console.log(this.form);
  }
}
```

And my html

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <div class='documents' formArrayName="documents">
      <div *ngFor="let document of documents; let i = index">
        <p-checkbox
            [formControlName]="i"
            name="doc" 
            [value]="document" 
            [label]="document.name" 
            [inputId]="document.id">
          </p-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the `binary` property in the `p-checkbox` component to true

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <div class='documents' formArrayName="documents">
      <div *ngFor="let control of form.get('documents').controls let i = index">
        <p-checkbox
            [formControl]="control"
            [binary]="true"
           >
          </p-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

result

```
{ "name": "", "documents": [ true, false, false, true ] }
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-startup-fx97sn)

**Updated!‍♂️**

base of the document structure you have to create a formArray of formgroup no form contyrol and save and unchange value like id or name as form control

```
  form;

  documnets = [   // sample data 
    {
      categoryId: 1,
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      categoryId: 2,
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      categoryId: 3,
      isSelected: false
    },
  ]

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      documents: fb.array([])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // add form control base of the data 
    this.documnets.forEach(doc => this.addControl(doc.categoryId, doc.isSelected));
  }

  get documentCtrl() {
    return (this.form.get('documents') as FormArray);
  }

  addControl(categoryId: number, isSelected: boolean) {
    this.documentCtrl.push(this.fb.group(   // create a form group
      {
        categoryId,
        isSelected
      }
    ));
  }

  save() {
    console.log(this.form);
  }
```

**tempale**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <div class='documents' formArrayName="documents">
      <div *ngFor="let doc of form.get('documents').controls" [formGroup]="doc">
        <p-checkbox
            formControlName="isSelected"
            [binary]="true"
            [label]="doc.get('categoryId').value"
           >
          </p-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-startup-jzo3yd)

Comment: But in this way, I won't be able to know which checkbox is checked,  As I want to know the value of checkbox `e.g: 'Domicile'`

Comment: @Programmer I have update the answer the main idea is to create a formArray of formGroup , hoop this will solve your problem ‍

Answer (score 0):

p-check allow be feed by an array. So you has NO a FormArray, just only two FormControls  see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-startup-kfemh9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      documents: [[2,3]] //<--the value of the control will be an array
                         //   but it's not a FormArray
    });
```

And your .html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <div class='documents' >
      <div *ngFor="let doc of documents; let i = index">
        <p-checkbox
            <!-- see that, acording the docs, you need use
               [formControl]="yourForm.controls['nameOF Control"
            -->
            [formControl]="form.controls['documents']"
            [label]="doc.name" 
            [value]="doc.value"
            >
          </p-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```